# Laravel Conditional Mass-Assignment

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, mass-assignment

When calling `User->update($data)` with mass-assignment, is it possible to only set the users password if one is passed in?

View:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Model:

```
<?php
class User extends Eloquent {            

    public static $rules = [
        'name' => 'required:max:32',
        'email' => 'required|max:128'
        'password' => 'min:8|max:128'
    ];

    // Allow mass-assignment for:
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

    // The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.         
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

}
```

Controller:

```
class UsersController extends BaseController {

    public function update($id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);    
        $validator = Validator::make($data = Input::all(), User::$rules);

        if ($validator->fails())
            return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();

        $user->update($data); // How do I only update password if password was passed in?
    }
}
```

Comment: `$user->password(Input::get('password')); $user->save();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
$user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password')); 

$user->save();
```

instead of:

```
$user->update($data);
```

to update only user password.